# JavaScript get parent element and write holder div for siblings

Tags: javascript, dom, element, parent

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="child1">Content here</div>
  <div class="child2">Content here</div>
</div>
```

At onload, I want to include a "holder" div, that holds all the parent's children like so:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="holder">
    <div id="child1">Content here</div>
    <div class="child2">Content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Knowing only the "child1" id, how can I add a holder div around itself and siblings?

**Considerations**

- The "child1" id is the only known identifier.
- The class "parent" and "child2" are dynamic name and will change, so can't be used as identifiers.
- needs to be vanilla JavaScript.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did your question originally have a jQuery tag and not say "vanilla JavaScript"? Just wondering since you got so many jQuery answers (from me included) and I'm sure it mentioned jQuery somewhere at the time I answered!

Comment: Sorry James, I didn't mention JQuery. (My post has not been edited since)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seeing as this has to be JavaScript (and not jQuery) and you can only indentify the child1 by id you could do something as crude as this:

```
var child1 = document.getElementById("child1"),
    parent = child1.parentNode,
    contents = parent.innerHTML ;
    parent.innerHTML = '<div id="holder">' + contents + '</div>';
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 for being the only one to notice "needs to be vanilla JavaScript"! I'm sure that point wasn't there when the question was first asked though...

Comment: But does this give you the answer. Why do you think innerHTML is crude?

Comment: If the "child2" div contains 3rd party content (e.g. images and script) will using .innerHTML not force the content to reload? (I'm not in front of my desktop to test.)

Comment: I'm not so sure about that as when testing I added  an external image to the child1 div and it does load when repainting (using innerHTML). Also you didn't mention that in your original problem...

Comment: Yes I agree, it was a further thought that came to mind when using  innerHTML and remote content. I may need to post another Question. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

He said no jQuery, this sounds like a homework assignment but:

```
var el = document.getElementById('child1');
var parent = el.parentNode;
parent.innerHTML = '<div id="holder">' + parent.innerHTML + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a litte-snipped to travel through DOM to find the first matching parentNode.

Hope this helps someone, sometime.

(/¯◡ ‿ ◡)⊃━☆ﾟ. * ･ ｡ﾟ,

```
function getFirstParentMatch(element, selector) {
  if (!element) {return element};
  element.matches(selector) || (element = (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'html' ? false : getFirstParentMatch(element.parentNode, selector)));
  return element;    
}
```

Comment: There is a error in your snippet, as `getFirstParent` should be `getFirstParentMatch`