# html tag inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, escaping, innerhtml

**HTML**

```
<a href="#1" class="current">1</a>    
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateHash() {
  var number = document.querySelectorAll('.current')[0].innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#xyz').innerHTML = '<a>'+ number + '</a>';
}
updateHash();
```

Obviously, this works.

However, I need the `<a>` to be `<a href="#>`

So when I do that:

```
document.querySelector('#xyz').innerHTML = '<a href="#'+ number + '"</a>';
```

It fails.

I don't know if this can be resolved with escaping the character; when I tried to escape " & #, it didn't work.

Maybe there isn't a way to escape the character for this scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Update]**

I solved it this way.

```
function updateHash() {
  var number = document.querySelectorAll('.current')[0].innerHTML;
  var tag = '<a href=#'    
  document.querySelector('#xyz').innerHTML = tag + number + '>next</a>';
}
updateHash();
```

Actually, I was doing the same thing as before.  But as pointed out, I wasn't seeing any output because my href was empty. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are not closing the `a` tag `<a></a>`
2. And also the `innerHTML` of the `a` tag is empty .so is not visible but its there in your `body`

**your mistake** .kindly check the `outerHTML`

```js
function updateHash(){
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.current')[0].innerHTML;
document.querySelector('#xyz').innerHTML = '<a href="#'+ number + '"</a>';
console.log(document.querySelector('#xyz').outerHTML)
}
updateHash();
```

```html
<a href="#1" class="current">1</a>    
    <div id="xyz"></div>
```

**solved**

```js
function updateHash(){
var number = document.querySelectorAll('.current')[0].innerHTML;
document.querySelector('#xyz').innerHTML = '<a href="#'+ number + '">innerhtml is empty</a>';
console.log(document.querySelector('#xyz').outerHTML)
}
updateHash();
```

```html
<a href="#1" class="current">1</a>    
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

Comment: LOL.  I wasn't seeing anything because my innerhtml was empty.  Just realized it myself.  Thank you so much!!

Sorry for posting such a dumb question.

Comment: ya.!.its just beginners problem.keep learning and keep coding...my answer is enough for you .Mark it as a answer .its helpful for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Going the jQuery route you could always call on `parent()` to get the HTML (assuming theres no other siblings within the parent:

```
$('#xyz').html( $('.current').parent().html() )
```

Comment: I've built the whole thing (SPA) with vanilla/plain javascript.  Wasn't going to add jQuery just to add this one pagination.   Thanks.

Comment: +1 yeah I generally go jQuery for convenience...but Vanilla JS can be more efficient at run time since you're not polling/loading a library

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11343905/2903486 has an example of `parentNode`

Comment: wow. I am sure that will come pretty handy down the line.  thanks.